# Entity Framework Core is not loading entities when using Include

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get list of users and its related companies and tags using Entity Framework Core 2.1.

When I'm using Include in the query, I'm expecting to get all the objects without lazy loading, but when I open the object, I'm seeing the list of companies and tags are returned using proxy, and iterating over the objects takes forever.

Here's my code:

```
IQueryable<User> usersQuery = _context.Users
    .Include(u => u.UserTags).ThenInclude(t => t.Tag)
    .Include(u => u.UserCompanies).ThenInclude(c => c.Company);

return usersQuery.ToList();
```

My ConfigureServices method:

```
        services.AddRouting(options => options.LowercaseUrls = true);
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
                {
                    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = StaticConfiguration.DefaultContractResolver;
                });

        JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = StaticConfiguration.DefaultContractResolver
        };

        services.AddCors();

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            options.UseLazyLoadingProxies();
            options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

        services.AddIdentity<User, UserRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Configure Identity options and password complexity here
        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
            options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
        });

        services.AddOpenIddict()
                .AddCore(options =>
                {
                    options.UseEntityFrameworkCore().UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
                })
                .AddServer(options =>
                {
                    options.UseMvc();
                    options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/authorazation/token");
                    options.AllowPasswordFlow();
                    options.AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
                    options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
                    options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
                    options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));
                    options.DisableHttpsRequirement(); // Note: Comment this out in production
                    options.RegisterScopes(
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OpenId,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Email,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Phone,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.Profile,
                        OpenIdConnectConstants.Scopes.OfflineAccess,
                        OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);
                })
                .AddValidation();

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.Consumer, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Consumer));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.Publisher, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Publisher));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.ConsumerOrPublisher, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Consumer, Roles.Publisher));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.AdministratorOrPublisher, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator, Roles.Publisher));
            options.AddPolicy(Policies.Administrator, policy => policy.RequireRole(Roles.Administrator));
        });

        LoadAllBySuffix(services, "Service", DependencyInjectionType.Singelton);
        LoadAllBySuffix(services, "Manager", DependencyInjectionType.Scoped);
        LoadAllBySuffix(services, "Repository", DependencyInjectionType.Scoped);

        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
        });

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new Info { Title = "PPR API", Version = "v1" });
            c.OperationFilter<AuthorizationFilter>();
            c.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OAuth2Scheme
            {
                Type = "oauth2",
                Flow = "password",
                TokenUrl = "/api/authorazation/token",
                Description = "Note: Leave client_id and client_secret blank"
            });
        });
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Where are you "opening" the objects? The query will be executed with the `ToList`-call and should include all objects you're explicy loading using `Include`. Just in case you're having a look and the `usersQuery` before executing `ToList`

Comment: What do u mean by using proxy?

Comment: @Lidor, Share your `ConfigureServices()` method code in `Startup` class please!

Comment: I added it to the question

Comment: @Lidor what’s proxy in your question ?